# FInding indices of multiple arrays satisfying a condition in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 3 huge arrays: `Array1`, `Array2` and `Array3`. All are of equal sizes and their dimension is `7000000x1`.

I am trying to find the indices of the arrays that satisfy a common condition using `find` command in Matlab, I used like this

```
I2 = find (Array1 > a1 & Array1 < a2 & ...
           Array2 > b1 & Array2 < b2 & ...
           Array3 > c1 & Array3 < c2 );
```

a,b and c are all contain scalar values.

`I2` is within a for loop (~7M iterations) and this operation takes enormous amount of time! Any suggestions for improving this line of code?

Comment: This is more than likely as fast as it's going to get. Is there any particular reason that you need `find` rather than just getting a logical array out?

Comment: I thought find is the easy way of doing it. Could you explain what is meant by getting the logical array out ?

Comment: Well what do you do later with `I2`? Do you use it to grab values out of something else? If so, you can omit `find` and just use the logical array returned by the rest of the statement to do the indexing for you

Comment: Yes, I use it to grab the values of a separate array, like array5 = array4(I2)

Comment: Yea then you don't need the `find` at all, just assign `I2` to the logical result of all of your comparisons and use *that* directly.

Comment: I apologize, I could not understand what you suggested, Would it be possible to provide an example with command line ?

Comment: `array5 = array4(Array1 > a1 & Array1 < a2  & Array2 > b1 & Array2 < b2 & Array3 > c1 & Array3 < c2 )`

Comment: Thanks, I shall try this.

Comment: Hi Mechanician!  Did Wolfie's answer solve your problem?  If so, please indicate that this is the case by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely quicker, using logical indexing not `find`

```
% Set up array of indices
I = 1:numel(Array1);

% Logical indexing the same as your Find function
I2 = I2(Array1 > a1 & Array1 < a2 & ...
        Array2 > b1 & Array2 < b2 & ...
        Array3 > c1 & Array3 < c3);
```

`I2` now contains the indices matching your criteria.

You said you would use this like

```
Array5 = Array4(I2)
```

If this is the only use, you can skip the `I2` creation entirely and use the same logical indexing used to create it, like so

```
Array5 = Array4(Array1 > a1 & Array1 < a2 & ...
                Array2 > b1 & Array2 < b2 & ...
                Array3 > c1 & Array3 < c3);
```